# Problem to save a xlsm with Python (openpyxl)

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsm, oserror

I trying to open an Excel with macros, modify a cell and save the excel with macros again, however is not working.

Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
 
#load excel file
workbook = load_workbook(r'FFM102-L-10-EBCL9.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
 
#open workbook
sheet = workbook['Track']
 
#modify the desired cell
sheet["B3"] = 5000

 
#save the file
workbook.save(r"FFM102-L-10-EBCL9.xlsm")
```

this is the answer:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "write_existing.py", line
> 56, in 
> workbook.save(r"FFM102-L-10-EBCL9.xlsm")   File "C:\Users\z004eu7h\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py",
> line 386, in save
> save_workbook(self, filename)   File "C:\Users\z004eu7h\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py",
> line 294, in save_workbook
> writer.save()   File "C:\Users\z004eu7h\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py",
> line 275, in save
> self.write_data()   File "C:\Users\z004eu7h\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py",
> line 60, in write_data
> archive.writestr(ARC_APP, tostring(props.to_tree()))   File "C:\Users\z004eu7h\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\zipfile.py", line
> 1814, in writestr
> with self.open(zinfo, mode='w') as dest:   File "C:\Users\z004eu7h\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\zipfile.py", line
> 1178, in close
> self._fileobj.seek(self._zinfo.header_offset) OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: What version of `openpyxl` are you using?

Comment: There are a few things you can try: 1. Check if the file actually exists on the location where you are saving it. 2. Make sure you have write permission to the folder where the file is being saved. 3. Make sure that the file you are writing to is not opened or used by another application.
To see if any of these 3 steps are a possible solution, consider writing the file in a new location. If that works, then your problem most likely lies in one of the three things I mentioned.

Comment: I´m using version 3.1.1 of openpyxl

Comment: Is the file on a networked or other type of remote storage?